# generic error occurred in GDI+ during System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I run a winform application. During the last couple of weeks I occasionally receive:
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.*

Full stack trace shows:

```
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Rectangle rect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.RepaintSplitterRect()
   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.ResizeSplitContainer()
   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement affectedElement, String affectedProperty)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmWindowPosChanged(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)*
```

I saw threads referring to this exception when trying to save a bitmap, but I'm not trying to save anything here.

Any ideas?

Comment: check if the image you want to change still exist.

Comment: It is a very generic error, used for most any System.Drawing system call.  With a stack trace like this you have a good reason to use Task Manager, add the GDI Objects column.  A steadily rising number for your process spells doom, use Dispose() where necessary.

Comment: Please show relevant code